# Getting SVG image from website

Tags: java, android, svg, web

Hello I'm trying to get an image from a website so I have tried different things.
I made a connection to the page and get all the info with an Input Stream and the use the SVG library in order to convert that code into an ImageView.
I hope you can tell me how to do this because I would appreciate it so much.
The page that I'm trying to get the image is this: http://cube.crider.co.uk/visualcube.php?fmt=svg&size=200&alg=S2M2E2
I wont copy the svg code because it is large. but if you press f12 you will find.

I also did in Eclipse an outputStream that had a copy of the image and save it on my pc... When I do that if I open it on the explorer I can see the image but in phone I don't know how to do it.
Thanks for help.

Here are my classes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.cubo);
    new AsynchTaskTest().execute();

}
```

And an Inner class

```
private class AsynchTaskTest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String path = "http://cube.crider.co.uk/visualcube.php?fmt=svg&size=200&pzl=7&cc=grey&r=z-15x-105&sch=yyyyyy&fc=ynyyynynnnynnnyyyyyyyyynnnyynyynyynnnyyynnynnnnny";

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(path);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");

            }

            return buffer.toString();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromString(aVoid);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code does not look bad. Does it work? What happens? Any problem?

Comment: I get an error when parsing. I tried to use vector asset with the code that I get and I can get an .xml with the picture but at this point I think 2 solutions: 1. Create an algorithm that convert a svg to xml but the points in .SVG are not the same as in the .XML. 2. Use Vector asset from code but I think that is not possible.

Comment: String aVoid contains the svg file. You can easily check if it is indeed the svg file. Starting with the amount of bytes you got and the original.

Comment: Why would you need to convert that svg file to an xml vile? Svg is xml.

Comment: But if I have this: <polygon fill='#0000F2' stroke='#000000'  points='-0.23182332941007,0.45988002752827 -0.018796486168384,0.59991168218429 -0.018796486168384,0.83016851261279 -0.2237011263268,0.68627250183624'/> that is one of the polygons of the .SVG file I need to use it in an Image View for example. Is just taking the .SVG content and put it in an ImageView

Comment: I think I know why I cant do that. I have seen a tutorial from where I downloaded de SVG.jar and when they do it their .SVG uses paths but the .SVG that I get uses Polygons so I think this library doesn't help me at all. I just need to know how the asset convert my .svg with polygons to a .xml with a vector and paths.

Comment: Welll cannot help you. Never did that before.